# Why does my Access form keep scrolling after the last record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm developing an Access 2007 Form.  It's main purpose is to display records (usually more than 1 page) with a Close button at the bottom.  Some highlights:

- It is Continuous
- Scroll Bars are enabled.
- I'm testing this with 41 records. About a page and a half.

The problem is: If you keep scrolling after the last record, the screen returns to about the middle record.  This doesn't seem like any standard GUI behavior I'm familiar with.

How can I get it to just stop scrolling when the last record is at the top of the screen?

#### Edit

I didn't even think about it when I posted this, but I get the expected behavior with Page Down and arrow keys.  It seems to be only with the mouse wheel that I get this behavior.

Comment: Access sometimes fills its forms with records on an as-needed basis.  Perhaps it is just filling the form with more records when you hit the bottom of the scroll bar?

Comment: I do not see this behaviour in a standard continuous form with a Jet/ACE back-end.

Comment: @Remou, Thanks, I took another look.  It seems to happen only when scrolling down with the mouse.  I tried it with 2 different mice and got the same strange behavior.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, with only 41 records, there's not that much to load.  Also, it's doing this continuously, i.e. the screen will jump from the last record to the middle record and repeat when I keep scrolling.

Comment: I wonder if this is your mouse, because I cannot get this to happen?

Comment: I was thinking it might be some random little Access option I set 6 months ago and forgot about, but I was able to replicate this behavior on 2 non-technical coworker's machines. (Also I didn't mention this before, but the Form itself has no Event Procedures, only the button itself)